# Expanded Usercards are not Showing Drop-shadow

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, profile-page, user-card

As per the [privilege description](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user), there should be a drop-shadow for a usercard that expands, however it is not showing now.

Expected behavior:

[image]

Current behavior:

No drop-shadow, but does expand:

[image]

[image]

(Screenshot captured in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8270264/9171697))

Reproducible in both Chrome 78.0.3904.70 and Firefox 69.0.3, with plugins (extensions) disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This intentional, but not ideal at the moment. I plan on having a preview card on *every* user. In my opinion, it's weird UX having it on *some* users and not all, regardless of a drop shadow or a bio.

I'll update the help article to be more accurate tomorrow. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: It's also weird UX not having some indicator that there is additional information to be displayed on hover. For example, I try hovering over your avatar, but I don't get anything: is my browser broken, or is there not supposed to be anything? Why would you not leave the shadow in place until you rolled out the preview card for every user as you eventually intend to do?

Comment: This response leaves me with a host of questions... was this opinion/unilateral plan to change a milestone feature discussed with the feature/Q&A team(s)? When was it going to be announced that one of the big milestone privileges was being done away with? Is some feature coming to replace this one for the (big) milestone of 1,000 reputation if/when this goes away?

Comment: I officially said "into it" [on this FR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334941/can-we-make-the-expanded-user-card-privilege-universal#comment1099163_334941) ;) Pretty much for the reason Aaron cites: it's weird UX. No plan to replace this one. It's not a significant privilege.